# keras error : Mnist on keras isnt working for me

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

i tried this code

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

print("gud to go")
(training, newtraining)= mnist.load_data()
```

and this error showed 
https://hastebin.com/eridajexev.sql

i have tried upgrading it and tensorflow but it shows error ,may be post how to do that ,that may work
help please?

edit:
im using version 1.9.0 of tensorflow

edit2 :

i used `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow==1.10.0` and still no and note that ,im using python3

Comment: This is not a TensorFlow problem, but a SSL certificate one, I am not sure how to fix it, because it could be caused by many things. Maybe you can download the file manually with a browser and place it in the right place, inside ~/.keras/datasets

Comment: How to download the file manually?

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz with any web browser.